# C++ function parameter takes an address of a pointer as an argument. How is this used? What is it for?

Tags: c++, function, pointers, reference

Imagine a function like this:

```
 function(Human *&human){
      // Implementation
 }
```

Can you explain what exactly a *& is? And what would it be used for? How is different than just passing a pointer or a reference? Can you give a small and explanatory sample?

Thank you.

Comment: You should see the type of the reference as "a reference to `Human*`", not "a `*&` to `Human`", then everything becomes clear: it's a pointer type which (the pointer itself, not what is stored behind it) is modifiable by reference. Like the referenced type is a "black box", as you would do by using a typedef or something like that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is like a double pointer. You're passing the pointer by reference allowing the 'function' function to modify the value of the pointer.

For example 'human' could be pointing to Jeff and function could modify it to point to Ann.

```
Human ann("Ann");

void function(Human *& human)
{
    human = &ann;
}

int main()
{
    Human jeff("Jeff");
    Human* p = &jeff;
    function(p);  // p now points to ann
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

```
void doSomething(int &*hi);
```

will not work. You cannot point to references. However, this:

```
void doSomething(int *&hi); // is valid.
```

It is a reference to a pointer. This is useful because you can now get this pointer passed into the function to point to other "Human" types.

If you look at this code, it points "hi" to "someVar". But, for the original pointer passed to this function, nothing will have changed, since the pointer itself is being passed by value.

```
void doSomething(int *hi)
{
    hi = &someVar;
}
```

So you do this,

```
void doSomething(int *&hi)
{
    hi = &someVar;
}
```

So that the original pointer passed into the function is changed too.

If you understand "pointers to pointers", then just imagine that, except when something is a reference it can be treated like a "non-pointer".

Comment: It's not a reference to a pointer. It's a pointer to a reference and it's not valid. Edit: the question is fixed now, but your answer isn't.

Answer (score 5):

"Takes an address of a pointer" - No, it doesn't. It <s>takes</s> supposed to take a [reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_%28C++%29) to a pointer.

However, this is a syntax error. What you probably meant is

```
rettype function(Human *&human)
```

(Yes, it's also missing a return type...)

Comment: they probably wanted a return type too.

Answer (score 5):

Since you wrote this code off the top of your head, I'm going to assume you meant to do something like this:

```
void f(T *&) {}
```

This function signature allows the pointer passed to become modifiable, something that isn't allowed with the alternate syntax `int *`. The pointer is effectively passed *by reference* as others here call it.

With this syntax, you are now able to modify the actual pointer and not just that which it points *to*. For example:

```
void f(int *& ptr) {
    ptr = new int;
}

int main() {
    int * x;
    f(ptr); // we are changing the pointer here

    delete x;
}
```

Summary (assume types are in parameters):

1. `T *`: We are only able to change the value of the object to which the pointer points. Changing the parameter will not change the pointer passed.
2. `T *&`: We can now change the actual pointer `T`, and the value of the object to which it points `*T`.

Comment: Thanks. So if I pass a pointer to a function, I can not change what it points to? But I can change the value that it points to? But now I can also change WHAT it points to.. Thanks I guess I understand it.

Comment: You can change what it points to (points to ann instead of jeff) and the data of the thing it points to: void function(Human*& human) { human->SetAge(35); }

Comment: @KorayTugay With this syntax, you are able to change both what the pointer points to, and that value of the object to which it points. Just doing `void f(int *) {..}` will restrict us to **only** being able to change the value of the object to which it points, and not the object the pointer is pointing. Do you need a clearer explanation?

Comment: @David: If I have "void function(Human *human)" and do something like this INSIDE the method: Human *newHuman = new Human(); newHuman->someProperty = "somevalue"; human = newHuman; // Have I not changed what the pointer points to?

Comment: @KorayTugay Nope: the parameter acts an alias in this case. The pointer passed to `function` will not be changed at all. The `human` pointer acts as a local variable that only holds the value of the passed pointer argument. Changing it won't affect the pointer at all.

Answer (score 4):

Even though it looks just like the address-of operator, it's not - it's a reference parameter. You use a reference when you want to be able to change the value at the caller's end. In this case the pointer is probably being set or changed within the function.