# Difference between T* and T*& C++

Tags: c++

What is the difference between the two copy functions below? I do not seem to see a difference between them. Specifically the void*& vs the void*.

So what is the difference between T*& and T*? When would I use one over the other? Also, if I made them accept const parameters, what would happen? What would the difference be?

```
#include <iostream>

void Copy(void* Source, void* Destination, int Size)
{
    //memcpy(Destination, Source, Size);
    char* S = static_cast<char*>(Source);
    char* D = static_cast<char*>(Destination);
    *D = *S;
}

void Copy2(void* &Source, void* &Destination, int Size)
{
    char* S = static_cast<char*>(Source);
    char* D = static_cast<char*>(Destination);
    *D = *S;
}


int main()
{
    int A = 2;
    int B = 5;
    int C = 7;

    void* pA = &A;
    void* pB = &B;
    void* pC = &C;

    Copy(pA, pB, 1);
    Copy2(pA, pC, 1);

    std::cout<< B <<std::endl;
    std::cout<< C <<std::endl;
}
```

Both of the above print "2". Both are the same no?

Comment: One's a reference. There's a world of difference there.

Comment: What? A reference to a pointer? :S What's the big deal with that? I don't see the difference still :l
They still do the same thing as far as I can tell at the moment.

Comment: Look at this, it will tell you exactly what you want to know: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13980482/c-function-parameter-takes-an-address-of-a-pointer-as-an-argument-how-is-this

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames, You're right. Unless I'm missing something obvious, there's no need for the reference.

Comment: Try changing the pointer value within Copy2, and examining it afterwards in main, in the debugger.  As it is, Copy2 passes the pointer via another (hidden) pointer, so access will be slower.

Comment: @JesusPlusPlus. Thank you for that link! Perfect. Thank you for the reply Matthew. I see now. BUT, what if the parameters were const? And what is the different between the void** and void*& then? They're both pointers to pointers no?

Comment: You are correct, @CantChooseUsernames, that a const reference avoids the overhead.  The difference between void** and void*& is syntactic, not semantic.

Comment: A reference and pointer are the same thing. I reference is just treated like a normal variable. void** and void*& mean the same thing, just that void** is treated like a pointer, void *& is treated like a normal variable. This was probably an unclear description, so I would just Google "C++ References Tutorial" or something.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One is a pointer, the other is a reference to a pointer.

Google both and pick up a C++ basics book.

Think of passing by pointer as passing a memory address by value (ie, a copy).  In the receiving function, you have a copy of the memory address and you can change where that memory address pointer points to, and what that destination memory contents looks like.  When you return from that function, the destination memory is still changed, but the original pointer is unchanged.

In contrast, a reference to a pointer allows you to change where that memory points to after you return from the function.  Otherwise it is the same.

A common usage is a funciton which allocates memory such as:

```
SomeClass *someClass = null;
PopulateSomeClass(someClass);
...

void PopulateSomeClass(SomeCLass* &someCLass)
{
   someClass = new SomeClass;
}
```

But really, google this for more detail - this is a more basic C++ concept.

For instance, a reference is typically implemented as a const * under the covers in the compiler.  So it is a const pointer to pointer.